# WSO2 ESB connections issue

Tags: connection, wso2, wso2-esb

Am working with wso2esb4.9.0 and having around 160 services which are http and are processed frequently, Initially when the server is started every thing is fine all service request response is up to the mark,

After 10-12 days the ESB server gets hanged does not process any request and no exception are seen in the log file even,They are some request  which may be piled up in the server and not allowing new connection to process.

when i do restart of the server all the connections get releases and works  for other 10-12 days again.

But doing a restart of the server may not be a good idea to do , where can i find these connections and close them if possible and am i missing any  config changes of wso2 esb.

Am trying to find some different connection number using JMX  and also what to know if any one face this issue and found the possible solution.

Comment: jms services, http services ? NIO or passthru ? which version of ESB ?

Comment: Hi @Jean-Michel thank you for the reply, am using wso2esb4.9.0 and all services are http services and pssthru.

Comment: You might try to enable logging for apache http client. Looks like connection leak.

Comment: Hi @simar i  have enabled the Apache log and done some load test but when i send a request with error data so the apache shown error as [proxy:error] [pid 6209] [client 127.0.0.1:36804] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /services/GetAssetMobile5.0

Comment: since esb failed to process the request this error appeared in apache and after 3mins esb pass-thought connection was also closed. so the connections are getting closed so there is no connection leakage as per the above observation

Comment: Is WSO2ESB behing nginx, httpd ?

Comment: yeah is behind apache2, For all https request  we use apache2 proxy pass to redirect the request to the esb server.